# For which $n ≥ 0$ is $2^n + 2 · 3^n$ divisible by $8$?

Tags: induction, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Stuck on this problem for some time:
For which $n ≥ 0$ is $2^n + 2 · 3^n$ divisible by $8$?
I've reached the conclusion that $n = 1$ is the only solution to the question at hand, but I cant quite prove that/why this is the case.

The properties of the evaluation of the expression as $n = 1$, $n = n + 1$ gives that the first term increases by a multiple of $2$, while the second by a multiple of 3, how can this help proving the solution?

Showing that $2^n + 2 · 3^n \equiv 0$ (mod 8) only when $n = 1$, why is it not enough to show the cases $0...7$? How would I go about proving the solution by modular arithmetic?

Going by induction, what would be the best way to prove that indeed 1 is the only solution - that the expression is not divisible by $8$ for any $n \geq 1$, in that case - how would this look? Or is there a better, different angle to attack it?

Comment: Hint:  if $n≥3$ then $8|2^n$ so that term disappears after the first three terms.  $3^n$ is either $1,3\;\mod(8)$.

Comment: @lulu That should be an answer.

Comment: @Aniket Ok, I'll post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on the argument presented in the comments.  Let $a_n=2^n+2^*3^n$.  We are only interested in $a_n\mod (8)$.

We note that $n≥3\implies 2^n\equiv 0\mod (8)$. So, for $n≥3$ we have $a_n\equiv 2^*3^n\mod (8)$.  But it is clear, from unique factorization, that $8$ never divides $2^*3^n$ (indeed it is easy to see that $2^*3^{2n}\equiv 2$ and $2^*3^{2n+1}\equiv 6$).  All that remains is to check $a_0, a_1,a_2$ to see that only $a_1$ is divisible by $8$.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you for posting it - being able to discard the first term does indeed simplify the problem a lot. Will accept answer if no other alternative shows up in the near future. How would we, by modular arithmetic without the use of when n $\geq 3$, reach the same solution? Is it even possible?

Comment: Well, I'd say this was modular arithmetic.  The fact that $2|8$ makes the powers of $2\mod (8)$ simpler to handle.  $3$ is prime to $8$ so we just need to solve $3^k\equiv 1$ to get the full picture of what the powers of $3$ look like.

Comment: Alright - would love to see a solution by induction as well to get a better grip on the topic overall. Thanks.

Comment: don't see a useful proof by induction.  I can rephrase my argument to sound inductive: assume $n≥3$ so that $a_n\equiv 2^*3^n$.  Inductively suppose that we know $a_n\not\equiv 0$ then $a_{n+1}\equiv\ 3*a_n\not\equiv 0$. But , personally, that feels very artificial.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is even, then $3^n \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ and so $2^n + 2 \cdot 3^n \equiv 2^n + 2 \not\equiv 0 \bmod 8$ because it is twice an odd number.

If $n$ is odd, then $3^n \equiv 3 \bmod 8$ and so $2^n + 2 \cdot 3^n \equiv 2^n + 6 \not\equiv 0 \bmod 8$ because it is twice an odd number if $n>1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n\geq 3$, $2^n+2\cdot 3^n$ is either $2$ or $6\pmod{8}$, since $3^2=9\equiv 1\pmod{8}$ and $8\mid 2^n$.

So we just have to check by hand the cases $n\in\{0,1,2\}$.